# How to add a tooltip to a modal launching button

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-modal, tooltip

I am using `Bootstrap` and `jQuery` to add some components to an app. I also want to add tooltips to some of those components. I am using `jQuery` to display the tooltips in my `index.html` page:

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
    })
</script>
```

To use this, I would simply add `data-toggle="tooltip" title="Tooltip goes here"` to the element tag on which I wanted to apply the tooltip.
I also have a button that launches a modal using `data-toggle="modal", which comes from` Bootstrap`. I cannot simply use the following to add both the tooltip and the modal launch functionality:

```
 <button
   type="button"
   class="btn"
   data-toggle="tooltip"
   data-target="#exampleModalCenter"
   data-toogle="modal"
   title="This launches the Program Form window"
 >
 Sign Up!
 </button>
```

What's an easy way to get booth the tooltip and modal functionailty on this button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call the bootstrap modal using Jquery click function will resolve your issue.

**Snippet:**

```js
$(".btn").click(function() {
  $('#exampleModal').modal('show');
});

$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div id="exampleModal" class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Modal body text goes here.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row" style="margin-top:50px">
    <div class="col text-center align-self-center">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="tooltip" title="This launches the Program Form window">Sign Up!</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This worked well. I had to tweak the element tags but it was easy.

Answer (score 1):

You can try by adding click event with jquery for the modal funcionality, then the tooltip method.

For instance:

```
$(function () {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').click(function(){
    $("#myModal").modal();
  });
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
});
```